# Size of JFilechooser

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfilechooser

I am trying to put a JFileChooser box on my GUI but if I just do this

```
JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser ();
```

then it will just show a huge file selection window on the panel (I do not want that), so I want to make a small box filechooser (with a name for example "choose file") that when I click it, a window will popup, so then I can choose the file.

Comment: Put an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) so that we can help you fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a button to open your file chooser and use `setPreferredSize()` method to make the file chooser smaller in size:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Choose a file!");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{ 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  { 
     JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
     fileChooser.setDialogTitle( "Choose a file" );
     fileChooser.setVisible( true );
     fileChooser.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(100, 100) );
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
filechooser.setPreferredSize (new java.awt.Dimension (800, 800));
```

before calling showOpenDialog with whatever Dimension you like.

But I would suggest to either maximize the Dialog, because in the moment I like to open a File, I don't like to watch something else - find a file, and close the dialog, without much scrolling, because somebody thought it looks more nice.

If you like to prevent wasting space, you can precalculate the needed size for the window, which might be a lot of work, but could pay off, if you use the Component frequently.